# following code is not working fine sometimes

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

i tried following code. it sometimes misses some key and value. Anybody can give idea why it is happening.

```
$test= array(rand(0, 9)=>"a",rand(0, 9)=>"b",rand(0, 9)=>"c",rand(0, 9)=>"d",rand(0, 9)=>"e");
print_r($test);
```

Comment: Array keys must be unique - your code can and will create duplicate keys

Comment: if 2 rand give same number it will be overwritten and remove first value

Comment: Can you please try to explain what you are trying to achieve with this code ?

I think the missing keys are just erased because the random generated keys are conflicting. If the first rand associated to "a" is 5, and the rand associated to "e" is 5 too, "a" will be erased and "e" will be set instead.

Comment: if you want to randomly arrange those letters, then `shuffle(array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'))` will be far more effective/reliable.

Comment: thanks all for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You override one value with another. For example if first rand() will create key with number 4 and last rand() will also draw 4 the first value will be overridden with last.

Example:

```
$test= array(4=>"a",1=>"b",5=>"c",2=>"d",4=>"e");
print_r($test);
```

Will print:

```
array(
    4 => "e"
    1 => "b"
    5 => "c"
    2 => "d"
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want something like this:

```
$array = ["a","b","c","d","e"];
shuffle($array);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($array);
echo '</pre>';
```

Output:

```
//Random
["b,"a","e","c","d"] //possibility 1
["e,"a","b","d","c"] //possibility 2
...
...
etc
```

Note: The array elements will be random each time you reload the page.